# install mysql 5.7 without root password

Tags: mysql

trying to install mysql 5.7 i get the prompt for a root password. 
after pressing enter i assume that the password for the root user will just be blank (null?)

if i try to connect to the server with `mysql -u root` the connection can't be established due to wrong authentication. if i add the `-p` parameter to get the prompt and leaving that empty will also result in bad authentication.

i'm not sure if can i completely remove the root password for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

What system user are you connecting from ?

If you don't provide a root password during installation, it does not just set an empty password, it refuses any password, and **only the system root user can connect**, just by typing :

```
mysql
```

Comment: ubuntu. that actually didn't worked. i cant connect with root (or you mean another root?)

Comment: just for record: setted-up a brand new installation, left the field empty and `mysql` doesn't work. somehow there is an empty password (or a password that is *something*)

Comment: I think it worked on Debian last time I tried, not sure about Ubuntu. I don't have a fresh install at the moment to try it on. (By the way, I did mean the regular root user).